# Showing progress bar in Shiny application

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to show progress bar or a message in Shiny application. I have app.R and helpcode.R

app.r

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
    column(width =3, numericInput('days','Days less than','15', width = 100)),
    submitButton("Submit")
    )
```

helpcode.R

```
new_function(input){
t_1 <- read.table("data/data_1.txt",sep="\t",skip=1)
  t_2 <- read.table("data/data_2.txt",sep="\t",skip=1)
}
```

I want to display status messages like - 
Data 1 loading when data1 is being read by the function
Data 2 loading when data2 is being read by the function

I am not able to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Have you tried something from https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html?

Comment: Is this for debugging purposes? AFAIK `fileInput` already offers an upload indicator of sorts.

Comment: @r2evans I am not able to integrate withProgress in this.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik It is not for debugging. I am not taking a file as input, file are read through function which are already present in my laptop.

Comment: Also try to use actionbuttons instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `withProgress` element inside the `new_function`

```
new_function(input) {
  withProgress(message = "Loading Data 1", value = 1, {
    t_1 <- read.table("data/data_1.txt",sep="\t",skip=1)
  })
  withProgress(message = "Loading Data 2", value = 1, {
    t_2 <- read.table("data/data_2.txt",sep="\t",skip=1)
  })
}
```